# ASP.NET MVC Site To Admin Befor Publish To Public

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Creating a website with ASP.net MVC, when a visitor post an article how to make it, first  come to administrator then publishing on the site?

Answer (score 2):

Do these things

1. Add a column IsApproved(bit) to your table where you store articles.
2. When a visitor posts an article, save the article with IsApproved as falsy(0)
3. Send an email to admin notifying the posting of a new article. (not mandatory)
4. Design a view for admin were he can read unapproved articles and then approve them. (ie make IsApproved='1')
5. Change the business logic on the site to allow only IsApproved='1' articles to be shown.

Hope this helps.